# UNUserNotificationCenter always denies authorisation

Tags: macos, unusernotificationcenter

I'm updating a legacy app to use the `UserNotifications` framework. After importing `UserNotifications` in my `AppDelegate.swift`, I request authorization using the following:

```swift
import UserNotifications

///...///

let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options: []) { (granted, error) in
  print("Granted: \(granted), error: \(error)")
  // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
}
```

However, this always prints the following:

```
Granted: false, error: Optional(Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1 "Notifications are not allowed for this application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notifications are not allowed for this application})
```

Am I missing a permission or entitlement somewhere? If I create a new project and add the notification to that, it works fine.

Comment: For me, the cause was different.
Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66108609/2348614

Answer (score 2):

I should have caught this sooner, but the issue was due to the project not correctly signing the application.

If you run into this issue, ensure that your Signing Team and Certificate is set.